# Вывод первого свободного номера

Tags: sql, mysql

Имеется таблица содержащая целочисленное поле (не индекс) с повторяющимися значениями. Надо сконструировать запрос на MySQL для вывода первого числа не встречающегося в этой таблице.
Схема данных:

```
create table services (
serviceid bigint auto_increment primary key,
vlanid mediumint default 1
);
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
select (t1.`vlanid` + 1) as res
from `services` t1 left join `services` t2 ON (t2.`vlanid` = t1.`vlanid` + 1) where t2.`vlanid` IS NULL
having res limit 1;
```

Comment: условие задачи "первого числа" не совпадает. Возможно в поле числа не по порядку.

Comment: Данные в поле vlanid заполнены в хаотичном порядке без какой-либо закономерности.

Comment: Ой, действительно не заметил :) Поправил :)

Comment: Все замечательно, но он ищет свободные номера, начиная со значения первой записи таблицы services. Мне же надо искать номер начиная с единицы.

Comment: А как насчёт транзакций? Это же всё не будет работать при конкурентном доступе.. или в MySQL не бывает параллельных запросов?

Comment: Предлагаю пока не думать о возможности изменения исходной таблицы во время выполнения запроса, т.к. слишком интенсивно использовать базу не предполагается.

Comment: > Все замечательно, но он ищет свободные номера, начиная со значения первой записи таблицы  services. Мне же надо искать номер начиная с единицы.
--
может, имеет смысл, добавить запись с еденицей "вручную", один раз...

Comment: Тоже об этом думал, но это все же костыль. Пришлось прибегнуть к самому быдлокодерскому варианту - проверять каждый номер от единицы до двух тысяч на нличие в базе, т.к. границы проверки могут меняться. Например, надо искать в промежутке от 500 до 1000.

Answer (score 0):

> но это все же костыль
>  1. так сделайте ДВА запроса. Один, как указано выше и второй на минимальное значение, существующее в таблице.
> и если минимальное больше 1, то возвращаете единицу,а иначе результат запроса...

1. если хочется все-таки сделать один запрос, то модифицируйте указанный выше:
       вместо имени таблицы services используйте (select vlaind from services union select 0 as vlaind from services) 
    :)